# http 500 error on get_headers method

Tags: php, http-status-code-500

My site went down recently and the hosting company helped recover it. After that i keep getting this error on one of my pages.

```
[22-Oct-2017 02:54:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare get_headers() in C:\inetpub\vhosts\mysite.com\httpdocs\html\blue\inc\ip_redirect.php on line 92
```

Here is the method that the code is referring to. I did check and this is whats causing the HTTP 500 errors.

```
function get_headers($url,$format=0)
{
    $url=parse_url($url);
    $end =  "\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = fsockopen($url['host'],  (empty($url['port'])?80:$url['port']), $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if  ($fp)
    {
        $out  = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host:  ".$url['host']."\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        $var  =  '';
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        stream_set_timeout($fp, 5);

        while (!feof($fp))
        {
            $var.=fgets($fp,  1280);
            $info = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

             if ($info['timed_out']) {
                echo 'Connection timed out!';
                return "";
             }

            if(strpos($var,$end))
            break;
        }
        fclose($fp);
        $var=preg_replace("/\r\n\r\n.*\$/",'',$var);
        $var=explode("\r\n",$var);
        if($format)
        {
            foreach($var  as $i)
            {
                if(preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z -]+):  +(.*)$/',$i,$parts))
                $v[$parts[1]]=$parts[2];
            }
            return  $v;
        }
        else
            return $var;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a framework? search through all the files for `function get_headers` and see if it is already defined.

Comment: Or make sure you aren't including the file that defines this function multiple times.  include_once() should be used for any files that declare functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `get_headers` is an internal function from PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

The method looks like some sort of polyfill. You have to either remove this method, or wrap it in a `function_exists` statement.

If none are options, than you might want to reach out to this scary method. Haven't used it myself.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-remove.php

Comment: how can i wrap the above method in`function_exists` to prevent this error.